# How to edit all values in a column in csv in R?

Tags: r, csv, substitution

I have a time series data which have currency data in one column. The data have '$' sign in this. How can I remove all the $ from the currency value.

My data :

```
        Date Dividend dat
1 1980-12-23   $0.001  26
2 1981-03-24   $0.001  27
3 1981-06-16   $0.001  28
4 1981-08-31   $0.001  29
5 1981-10-05   $0.003  30
6 1982-03-23   $0.001  31
```

I want data like this:

```
        Date Dividend dat
1 1980-12-23   0.001  26
2 1981-03-24   0.001  27
3 1981-06-16   0.001  28
4 1981-08-31   0.001  29
5 1981-10-05   0.003  30
6 1982-03-23   0.001  31
```

Comment: `gsub("$", "", dat$Dividend)`

Comment: Wouldn't you have to add `fixed = T`?

Comment: simple `gsub` would do that .

Answer (score 1):

`sub` with `fixed=TRUE` will substitute one literal string for another.  You need `fixed=TRUE` as `$` is a special character, with meaning in a regular expression (it indicates the end of the string).

`transform` makes the syntax a bit better for the command.  `transform` does not alter the data frame, so you would need to use the return value, perhaps assigning it back to the original variable.

```
transform(d, Dividend = sub('$', '', Dividend, fixed=TRUE))
        Date Dividend dat
1 1980-12-23    0.001  26
2 1981-03-24    0.001  27
3 1981-06-16    0.001  28
4 1981-08-31    0.001  29
5 1981-10-05    0.003  30
6 1982-03-23    0.001  31
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `gsub` with `fixed=TRUE` as explained by @Mathew.

```
ginidata <- read.table(text = "Date Dividend dat
1 1980-12-23   $0.001  26
2 1981-03-24   $0.001  27
3 1981-06-16   $0.001  28
4 1981-08-31   $0.001  29
5 1981-10-05   $0.003  30
6 1982-03-23   $0.001  31")
ginidata$Dividend <- gsub("$","",ginidata$Dividend, fixed = TRUE)

ginidata
#         Date Dividend dat
# 1 1980-12-23    0.001  26
# 2 1981-03-24    0.001  27
# 3 1981-06-16    0.001  28
# 4 1981-08-31    0.001  29
# 5 1981-10-05    0.003  30
# 6 1982-03-23    0.001  31
```